# Is "who did what" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, questions

Sometimes I wish to know what each person in a group of people did, or where each person went, or which book goes where. Is it correct to say,

> - Who went where?
> - Who did what?
> - Who told whom?
> - Which book goes where?

If not, what is the grammatical way of framing such questions?

Comment: It's perfectly all right. There can be many interrogatives in a question, but only one can be the first interrogative, signalling the question. The others remain in place.

Comment: 'Who wrote what on whose what?' appears famously in _1066 and All That_ - this is stretching things a little far.

Comment: The following appears here on EL&U for the very first time:  "Who did what to whom--and where and when and how and why?" The words in quotation marks summarize neatly what a professor of Criminology 101 might say to his class of detective wannabies on the first day of class!

Comment: Haha. Thanks for the comments everyone. That settles a major doubt of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All four are grammatically correct.

The comments are good here, but I wish people would put answers in the answers section because the question remains unanswered even though the OP has the answer(s) in the comments!

Comment: Good point about answers and comments.  The moderators have told me in the past that my questions are more like comments!  To each his or her own.